# SwiftUI stack layout, what is "least flexible child"?

Tags: layout, swiftui

I'm watching the WWDC 2019 talk [Building Custom Views with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237/). Around 14:50 he's describing the algorithm for the layout, and he says "we divide the space into 3 equal parts and propose one of those for the size of the *least flexible child*".

[image]

How does the parent (the `HStack`) know which child is the "least flexible"?

Up to that point in the talk, the explanation of the layout algorithm in SwiftUI had been clear to me -- parent views propose a size to child views, and child views respond with their desired size. In this case it sounds like some other property of each child is consulted *before* the size is proposed to the children. But what is that property and how do you control it from code?

Comment: I think that, but I can't find any documentation for this thought, the parent view actually proposes the size to all of its children. All the children answer to the parent, some children answer  with a less flexible size (for instance a Text that is big as its content) and other children with a more flexible size. Then, the parent starts the actual sizing process from the least flexible child to the most flexible child.

Comment: @matteopuc , can u give a specific example of what size is flexble , and what size is less flexbile? thanks